How to connect tracing open telemetry in golang project?
I have this part of the code:
    g, gCtx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

    for _, pair := range app.Settings.Pairs {

        feederCtx, feederSpan := telemetry.Tracer.Start(gCtx, fmt.Sprintf("start-market-feeder-%s", pair))
        feederSpan.SetAttributes(attribute.String("pair", pair))

        app.dataFeed.SubscribeMarketsStat(feederCtx, pair, "exchangebot")
        for _, observer := range observers {
            if err := app.dataFeed.SubscribeObserverMarkets(feederCtx, "exchangebot", pair, observer); err != nil {
                appLogger.Error(err)
            }
        }

        g.Go(func() error {
            defer feederSpan.End()
            return app.dataFeed.StartMarketsStatFeeder2(feederCtx, pair)
        })
    }

In Jaeger, I get the following trace
Image service&operation in Jaeger
How can I ensure that "exchange-bot client-grpcSubscriptionMarket" is a child element of "exchange-bot start-market-feeder V2"?
It would be possible to redesign the structure so that all functions are called sequentially, but it has already been implemented this way, and I'm interested to know if there's a way to achieve this without changing the structure
